# Restkit response mapping for get API

Tags: objective-c, swift, restkit

I'm new for Restkit response mapping. I'm not able to map it properly. I have Event and Venue model with all necessary attributes. Could any one set request mapping for it.
Thanks in advance.

```
*Printing description of mappingResult:
<RKMappingResult: 0x7b1e2da0, results={
    "" =     {
        events =         (
                        {
                date = "Saturday,17 Jan 2015";
                "event_list" =                 (
                                        {
                        "already_attending" = 0;
                        attending = 1;
                        description = "<null>";
                        "event_end_date" = "Saturday,17 Jan 2015 07:30pm";
                        "event_start_date" = "Saturday,17 Jan 2015 07:30pm";
                        id = 54b3e2fe7265646a782f0000;
                        "is_limited" = 1;
                        "is_private_community_event" = 1;
                        name = Drinks;
                        picture = "http://veozen.systech-soft.com/pictures/original/missing.png";
                        "user_picture" = "http://veozen.systech-soft.com/profile_pictures/original/missing.png";
                        venue =                         {
                            latitude = "51.505968";
                            longitude = "-0.027865";
                            "venue_address" = "4.3";
                            "venue_name" = "Cafe Brera";
                            "venue_picture" = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?photoreference=CnRnAAAAZk6z2twchk-xU6AGo-ZwK6ykDWTsf6LWh6TjX0ho7K5gLqr4-FkAtGpSr9MNK4Ytc7ejQerAvTO7w2_-fFUoTFF_W_vG3isNz3rKzxf-WMep-VC2loBE2Exmt4Lbr8q4kTKdwUNpckm5Lqy1b7UXTBIQeZjov6oDTrT21gjtv0XzYBoUetjjOaRuGeX262g6k4V8U0-o1H8&key=AIzaSyDfB1L32kL2bgdd0Wz5IJTeI0OiHONLmbQ&sensor=false&maxwidth=320";
                        };
                    }
                );
            }
        );
 }; 
}>*
```

Comment: Show the mapping code and explain more what it does wrong.

Comment: Appdelegate.m [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:loginResponseDescriptor];